# Stange behavior: python converting a dictionary to a list unintentionally

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I'm accessing a Web based API, and using the following code as my lowest level of abstraction (with debugging prints).

The following strange behavior happens only happens for certain api calls, namely the ones where the only thing returned is a single dictionary object. I'd like to understand more about this behavior, and how to fix it.

The problem is that python is converting the dictionary object returned by .json() into a list on the

```
ret += res.json()
```

line.

However, the code works as intended for API calls that return an list of dictionary, mixed type lists, ect.

```
import requests, json, re

def api_get(s):
    username = "username"
    password = ""
    url = 'base_url' + s

    ret = []

    while url != None:
        res = requests.get(url, auth=(username, password))
        print ret
        print res.json()
        ret += res.json()
        print ret
        try:
            url = re.search('<(.+?)>; rel="next"', res.headers['link']).group(1)
        except (AttributeError, KeyError) as e:
            url = None

    return ret
```

This is the output for this is:

> []
>
> {u'activities': [{u'body': u'stuff', u'created_at':
>   u'2014-07-29T05:31:14Z', u'user': None, u'subject': None}], u'notes':
>   [], u'emails': []}
>
> [u'activities', u'notes', u'emails']

As you can see, the values printed of res.json() and ret after ret += res.json() are inconsistent.

Comment: Thanks for the responses! I see, so the reason it works as intended api calls that return lists/arrays of dicts is because it's iterating over the lists and arrays instead of over a dict. What would be the best way to fix this code that that it works with both calls that return lists and single dictionary objects? Using .append wouldn't work, because it would break the first situation (appending a list  would create a list of lists). Maybe do some type checking? Although that's a little ugly.

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant to use [`.append()`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) instead of `+=`. Let's look at an example:

```
ret = [1, 2, 3]
ret += {'value': 4}
print ret
```

This prints:

```
[1, 2, 3, 'value']
```

which is exactly what you observe. When you use `+=` it just appends the json's (dictionary's) keys.

If you had used `.append()` like this:

```
ret = [1, 2, 3]
ret.append({'value': 4})
print ret
```

you would get:

```
[1, 2, 3, {'value': 4}]
```

Answer (score 1):

When you run code like `mylist += something`, Python is going to try to iterate through `something`. This is equivalent to running:

```
for i in something:
    mylist.append(i)
```

When you iterate through a dictionary, you get a list of its keys.

```
>>> for i in {"a": 1, "b": 2}: print i
a
b
```

That's why you see the keys of your dictionary being added to the list. If you just want to add a dictionary to a list without all this hubbub, you can use `.append()`, like so:

```
>>> a = []
>>> a.append({"a": 1, "b": 2})
>>> print a
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2}]
```

Answer (score 0):

No, its doing the right thing. When you iterate a dict, you get its keys. `list += iterable` iterates the right hand side and adds that to the list. Because the right hand side is a dict, its keys are added to the list.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this just

```
alist = []
adict = {'one': 1, 'two', 2, 'three', 3}
alist += adict
```

`alist += adict` is equivalent to `alist.extend(iter(adict))`

`iter(adict)` returns the keys of `adict`

Therefore, the behavior you're describing is expected.

Comment: I see, so the reason it works as intended api calls that return lists and arrays is because it's iterating over lists instead of over a dict. What would be the best way to fix this code that that it works with both calls that return lists and single dictionary objects? Using .append wouldn't work, because I don't want to append entire lists at once.